# how to config Intellij Idea live template's applicable context?

Tags: intellij-idea, live-templates

I want to create a live templates group for my custom file type, but when i pick a applicable context, there are a list of kind of file type or language but my custom file type.

Is the list predefined and can not extend?

Answer (score 1):

The available context types depend on the enabled plugins. It says so (and not much more) here in the Jetbrains help page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/live-templates-2.html

If your custom file already has a plugin, maybe all you have to do is add it. For example adding the plugin Perl adds Perl5 to the list.

Otherwise you need to look into how to create an extension. More on that here: http://www.jetbrains.org/display/IJOS/Writing+Plug-ins

Good luck!

Comment: @JohnHou, Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.